# What is this command called?

Tags: spring, properties

I've seen this syntax in many places, such as when using javscript, thymeleaf(spring), properties files etc.

```
//ex; in properties file. Where are the values coming from?
 ${someText} 
 ${set.config.username}
```

What is ${} actually called? I am trying to do research on understanding where the values are coming from when it is in the curly brackets. But when I google ${} relevant suggestions show up. I would need the actual name of this so I can get more crisp information on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the phrase you are looking for here is "string interpolation" or "variable interpolation". Basically, something (whatever is processing or pre-processing the properties file in this example) should replace `${someText}` with the value that is defined elsewhere (by user input, by an environment-specific config, something else...), probably in the form `someText=blah blah blah`.

Comment: Thank you!, I will accept answer when times up. Now I can continue with my research

Comment: Explained here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Spring and Thymeleaf, the contents inside are written in "Expression Language", which may be a useful search term to find more information.

Comment: Would you happen to know how expression language are used in .yml files?